# TRACE Macro Error When Attempting to Pass String Variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, trace

My calls to the `TRACE` macro are resulting in an error when I attempt to pass a string to it like so:

```
TRACE(_T("PrintAppMsgTrace: %s"), _T(GetCmdIdStr( pMsg[APP_MSG_CODE_OFFSET] )));
```

This is the error I get in the console window output:

> _CrtDbgReport: String too long or IO Error

Here is the prototype for `GetCmdIdStr`:

```
char * GetCmdIdStr( BYTE id );
```

`GetCmdIdStr` returns a pointer to memory containing something like "APP_ZDO_NLME_LEAVE_REQ".  It essentially works like this:

```
char * GetCmdIdStr( BYTE id )
{
    return "APP_ZDO_NLME_LEAVE_REQ";
}
```

Why am I getting this error?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_T()` macro is used on string literals.  It expands to either just the original string literal, if you're compiling ANSI, or the string literal with an `L` prefix if you're compiling UNICODE.  You can't apply it to the return value of a function.

If possible, the simplest thing to do would be to change the `GetCmdIdStr` function to return `TCHAR` instead of `char`:

```
TCHAR * GetCmdIdStr( BYTE id )
{
    return _T("APP_ZDO_NLME_LEAVE_REQ");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly why, but that seemed to do the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: The reason is the L prefix from the _T() macro makes the compiler allocate 2 bytes per character rather than 1 byte per character.  It can do this at compile-time on a literal, but it can't do it at run-time on a variable, like you were returning from the function.  So, depending on compiler settings, you were passing a 1-byte-per-character string to the TRACE function expecting a 2-byte-per-character string.